# how to display list of valid coupon code on cart page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, coupon-codes

how to display list of **valid** coupon code on cart page in magento 2

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
        $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
        $CatalogSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
        $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Contact\Block\CustomSession');  
        $SalesRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
        $getRules = $SalesRule->getCollection();
        $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

        $products = $blockObj->getProducts(); // this will also work using custom session block
foreach ($products as $product) {
        foreach ($getRules as $rule) {
$rules = $SalesRule->load($rule->getId());
$item->setProduct($product);
$validate = $rules->getActions()->validate($product);
            if ($validate == true) {

                echo "coupon -".$rule->getCode()."'>".$rule->getCode()." - ".$rule->getDescription()." coupon";
                 echo "<br>";
                # code...
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }
     }
```

Above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the collection with "is_acrive" filed.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
    $SalesRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
    $getRules = $SalesRule->getCollection();
    $getRules->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $activerulecoll = $getRules->getData();

    foreach ($activerulecoll as $rule) {
        print_r($rule['rule_id']);

    }
?>
```

Comment: getting same out put. I need coupon code which can apply to the cart product wise or cart wise not all list of coupon code.

Comment: I got all coupon code of other brand and category too. I want to show product/cart specific coupon code which is valid to apply.